# Google Places API acting strange

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm about to incorporate a google places API search into my application. When enabling the places service in the API dashboard, everything goes fine. I click the question mark, then try it now, and a new tab opens with json results (long array of place objects) from a test usage with a random location and my API key.

The URL it uses:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.88471,151.218227&radius=100&sensor=true&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

What's weird is that when I refresh this page, I get a REQUEST_DENIED error. No idea why. I also can't get a valid request response when I construct my own request url. What's going on here?

[image: Link to 'try it out!']

Comment: It may be working now. Not sure what the problem was...

Comment: Since this appears to have resolved itself, should this question just be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what the problem was... You **need** to set the location header to match the pattern you supplied when you registered your API key, otherwise the request will be denied.